# POST multiple objects from Angular controller to Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am able to send a raw json object from my angular controller which is deserialized to a known type at my web api method.  This is great but I now need to be able to send other parameters in the same request, these could be json objects or simple types like string or int.

I've seen articles such as [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/F2aL081113-Passing-multiple-complex-type-parameters-to-ASP.NET-Web-API.html) which describe exactly my problem but they are sending their request from codebehind rather than client side.

I tried to construct a json array and send this in but I get the following message : **'Cannot create an abstract class'**.

**Controller Code (adapted)**

```
var request = {
            params:[]
        };

        request.params.push(jsonObjectA);
        request.params.push({"someString" : "ABCDEF"});

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: targetUri,
            data: request
        })
```

**Web API Method Signature**

```
 public JsonResult TestMethod(JArray request)
```

Does this approach sound sensible?  I really want to avoid having to create dto objects for every request if I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK managed to get it working by following [this article](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/).

Then I was able to use simple and complex types in my api method signatures :

```
public JsonResult MyAction(StonglyTypedObject myObj, string description)
```

and I am passing in the values in the data parameter :

```
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: targetUri,
            data: {
                myObj: myObj,
                description: "desc here"
            }
        }).success(...
```

This was the cleanest solution I could find, hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

In post method first parameter is url and second one is object, what ever u want u can pass in this object....

It may be help for u..

Comment: thanks but I also know how to find the angular docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

also, please read the question more carefully in future, I was asking how I can add 2 parameters to the request rather than one as shown in the code snippet you posted.