# How to send POST in angularjs with multiple params?

Tags: angularjs

I want to send multiple parameters using angularjs HTTP post service.

Here is client side code:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:53263/api/Products/", [$scope.product, $scope.product2]).
        then(function (data, status, headers, config) { alert("success") },
             function (data, status, headers, config) { alert("error") });
```

Here is server side code:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public void Post([FromBody]Product product,[FromBody]Product product2)
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var newProduct = productRepository.Save(product);
}
```

But when I make the post I get error.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think u have to pass isArray: true in config params

Comment: Please see this [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829124/post-multiple-objects-from-angular-controller-to-web-api-2) which help me to solve my similar problem

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Consider a post url with parameters **user** and **email**

params object will be

```
 var data = {user:'john', email:'john@email.com'};
    $http({
      url: "login.php",
      method: "POST",
      params: data
    })
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you are doing, even if this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yep, I just came across this and while it may seem useful to others. I have no clue of what exactly to do with this. -1

Comment: yes it worked, this way, it makes difference. however $http.post(url, data) doesn't

Comment: @Ram there is a difference. In $http.post(url, data), "data" is here the body of the POST request. In the above example ..params: data.. "data" are the query params.

Answer (score 44):

**Client Side**

Data needs to be grouped in an object array as payload - `Indata`:

```
var Indata = {'product': $scope.product, 'product2': $scope.product2 };
```

Pass the payload through `$http.post` as the second argument:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:53263/api/Products/", Indata).then(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert("success"); 
},function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert("error"); 
});
```

**Server Side**

Create a Data Transfer Object(DTO) class as such:

```
public class ExampleRequest {
   public string product {get; set;};
   public string product2 {get; set;};
}
```

The class below accepts DTO with the same property names which the payload is carrying.

```
public void Post(ExampleRequest request)
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var newProduct = productRepository.Save(request.product);
}
```

In above class, `request` contains 2 properties with values of `product` and `product2`

Comment: OP is using what appears to be web-api specific C# syntax, which means that at most, only one object can be read from the body of a POST request.  Calling $http.post("url", payload) is going to append payload to the body of the request.  Prior to web api, this was fine, but now, it will *NOT* parse values from this object.  You either need a single receiving object to de-serialize to or you need send some data via other methods.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what is your backend technology.
If your backend technology accepting JSON data.
**data:{id:1,name:'name',...}**

otherwise, you need to convert your data best way to do that creating Factory to convert your data to
**id=1&name=name&...**

then on $http define content-type.
you can find full article @https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: {username: $scope.userName, password: $scope.password}
}).success(function () {});
```

ref:[How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

**!important**
about encodeURIComponent(obj[p]) will transfer object the way implicit. like a date value will be converted to a string like=>'Fri Feb 03 2017 09:56:57 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)' which I don't have any clue how you can parse it at least in back-end C# code. (I mean code that doesn't need more than 2-line)
you can use (angular.isDate, value.toJSON) in date case to convert it to more meaningful format for your back-end code.

I'm using this function to comunicating to my backend webservices...

```
 this.SendUpdateRequest = (url, data) => {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                transformRequest: function (obj) { return jsontoqs(obj); },
                data: { jsonstring: JSON.stringify(data) }
            });
        };
```

and bellow code to use it...

```
webrequest.SendUpdateRequest(
  '/Services/ServeicNameWebService.asmx/Update',
  $scope.updatedto)
  .then(
      (res) => { /*/TODO/*/ },
      (err) => { /*/TODO/*/ }
);
```

in backend C# I'm using newtonsoft for deserializing the data.

Answer (score 4):

You can only send 1 object as a parameter in the body via post.  I would change your Post method to

```
public void Post(ICollection<Product> products)
{
}
```

and in your angular code  you would pass up a product array in JSON notation

Comment: really there  is no way to send multiple params in angularjs $http?

Comment: not in the body unfortunately but you can pass strings or numerical data in the url instead but not sure if that's a an option for you if Product is a complex object. 
Edit: just to note, this isn't a limitation specific to angular, it's HTTP

Comment: Do you have any idea can I send simple type(string,int etc...) in POST budy?

Comment: yes you can send a string or int in the post body just as you do above but again you are limited to only 1.  if you need to send multiple strings / ints you'll have to use POST to your API with your parameters attached to the URL.  this is a more common approach for GET though (ie querying for a product using it's ID.  As Dev-One posts you can also create a DTO to house the properties you need to transmit.  That way you get multiple parameters encapsulated in a single object

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC and Web API chances are you have the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package installed.This library has a class called [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) which allows you to pass through multiple parameters:

**Api Controller:**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        Product product = data["product"].ToObject<Product>();
        Product product2 = data["product2"].ToObject<Product>();

        int someRandomNumber = data["randomNumber"].ToObject<int>();
        string productName = product.ProductName;
        string product2Name = product2.ProductName;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module("app", []);
    myApp.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.AddProducts = function () {
            var product = {
                ProductID: 0,
                ProductName: "Orange",
            }

            var product2 = {
                ProductID: 1,
                ProductName: "Mango",
            }

            var data = {
                product: product,
                product2: product2,
                randomNumber:12345
            };

            $http.post("/api/Product", data).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("An error occurred during the AJAX request");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <input type="button" ng-click="AddProducts()" value="Get Full Name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var headers = {'SourceFrom':'web'};
  restUtil.post(url, params, headers).then(function(response){
```

You can also send `(POST)` multiple params within `{}` and add it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
let Params= new HttpParams();
Params= Params.append('variableName1',variableValue1);
Params= Params.append('variableName2',variableValue2);

http.post<returnType>('api/yourApiLocation',variableValue0,{headers, params: Params})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the direct solution:

```
// POST api/<controller>
[HttpPost, Route("postproducts/{product1}/{product2}")]
public void PostProducts([FromUri]Product product, Product product2)
{
    Product productOne = product; 
    Product productTwo = product2; 
}

$scope.url = 'http://localhost:53263/api/Products/' +
                 $scope.product + '/' + $scope.product2
$http.post($scope.url)
    .success(function(response) {
        alert("success") 
    })
    .error(function() { alert("fail") });
};
```

If you are sane you do this:

```
var $scope.products.product1 = product1;
var $scope.products.product2 = product2;
```

And then send products in the body (like a balla).

Comment: Great answer! I dont't want to create an other dto class to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $scope.username;
var pwd = $scope.password;

var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../Account/LoginAccount',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    params: { username: name, password: pwd }
}

$http(req).then(function (responce) {
    // success function
}, function (responce) {
    // Failure Function
});
```

Comment: By Using above code, we can send POST with multiple params in Angular JS

Answer (score 0):

You can also send (`POST`) multiple params within `{}` and add it.

Example:

```
$http.post(config.url+'/api/assign-badge/', {employeeId:emp_ID,bType:selectedCat,badge:selectedBadge})
    .then(function(response) {
        NotificationService.displayNotification('Info', 'Successfully Assigned!', true);
    }, function(response) {
});
```

where `employeeId`, `bType` (Badge Catagory), and `badge` are three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

add the transformRequest as below to send multiple params to backend

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
            var transform = function(data) {
                return jq.param(data);
            };
            var config = {
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                },transformRequest: transform
            };

      var params={
            blogPostJson:JSON.stringify($scope.blogPost),
            publish:$scope.blogPost.active
        };
        var url = "${createLink(controller : 'cms', action : 'saveBlog')}";
            $http.post(url,params, config).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                var data = response.data;
               // var status = response.status;
                if (data.error) {
                    alert('error :' + data.error);
                } else {
                  //  alert('Success');

                }

            }).catch(function onError(response) {
                //console.log ("Unable to save Alcohol information");
            });
```