# How to pass array data from angularjs to c# mvc model?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model

```
public class StudentDataModel
{
    public StudentDataModel();

    [JsonProperty("student_data")]
    public StudentData Data { get; set; }
}



public class StudentData 
{
    public StudentData ();
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

In javascript file i have students data like

```
  $scope.students=[];
$scope.saveStudent=function(){
 return $http.post("/Student/Save?studentData=" + $scope.students)
        .then(function (result) {

        });
};
```

In students array contains number of students.

Mvc code:-

```
public async Task<JsonNetResult> Save(List<StudentData> studentData )
    {
       return new JsonNetResult { Data = response };
    }
```

In the above code i want to pass students array to mvc controller. mvc controller was hitted but data was not passed.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957248/how-to-send-post-in-angularjs-with-multiple-params/30957308#30957308

Comment: `$http.post("/Student/Save", $scope.students);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a request class, and pass those parameters form the UI

```
$scope.saveStudent=function(){
var inData = {'Students': JSON.stringify($scope.students)};
 return $http.post("/Student/Save?studentData=", inData )
        .then(function (result) {

        });
};
```

A DTO class for the request:

```
public class StudentDto
{
  public string Students;
}
```

Then in the MVC Controller:

```
public async Task<JsonNetResult> Save(StudentDto request )
{
   var studentList = JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject<>(request.Students).ToList();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send `$scope.students` as `data` i.e. Request content of method [`$http.post(url, data, [config]);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

```
$http.post("/Student/Save", $scope.students);
```