# How to combine inserting these single and multiple json in angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs, mongodb

I had a problem with multiple insert in angularJS. 
$scope.tes from:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tes" name="tes"/><br>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
$scope.data = [{matapelajaran : '', dosen: ''}];
$scope.tambah = function(){
            $scope.data.push({matapelajaran : '', dosen: ''});
$scope.cancel = function(){
            $scope.data.splice($scope.data.length-1);
        };

    $scope.simpan = function(){
        $http.post('http://localhost/bismillah/server.php?action=update',$scope.data,{"tes":$scope.tes}).success(function(response){
            if(response > 0){
                $scope.data = [{matapelajaran: '', dosen: ''} ];
                $scope.pesan = response +' Data telah berhasil di simpan';
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            });
        }
```

And here's my server.php

```
<?php

$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('apaan');


switch($_GET['action']){
    case 'insert' :
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $tes = $data->tes;
        $query = $db->siswa;
        $query->insert(array("tes"=>$tes));
    case 'update' :
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $tes = $data->tes;
        $i = 0;
        $query = $db->siswa;
        $query->insert(array("tes"=>$tes));
        foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $query->update(array("tes"=>$tes),array('$addToSet'=>array("matapelajaran"=>array("matapelajaran"=>$v->matapelajaran, "dosen"=>$v->dosen))));
            $i++;
        };
        echo json_encode($i);
        break;
}
```

Both of those codes couldn't work for me. I don't know with this part:

```
$http.post('http://localhost/nothing/server.php?action=update',$scope.data,{"tes":$scope.tes}).success(function(response){
```

Please help me..

Comment: Could you still more elaborate like, what's the sample json inside $scope.data and is {tes"$scope.tes} a key to identify a record ?

Comment: Could you please look at my post again ? It has explained bout sample json inside both of $scope.data and {"tes":$scope.tes}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32304405/7203487 You may check this.