# angular POST not working with servlet

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, servlets

I am trying to use angularjs POST (or even GET) to a servlet with the following:

```
var json = { hello: "world" }

var deffered = $q.defer();
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" },
    request: JSON.stringify(json)
}).then(data) {
     if(data.data) {
          deferred.resolve({
               response : data
          });
     )
})
return deffered.promise;
```

within the servlet, simple:

```
String val = request.getParameter("request")
```

it never seems to see it
I have tried:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ request: json })
data: { request: json }
"request" : JSON.stringify(json)
```

etc

if I comment out the getParameter and just return a generic value using Gson

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("This", "works");
response.getWriter().print(new Gson().toJson(json));
```

that comes back fine so is there something within the angular POST I am doing wrong here? I have also tried using "GET" instead but same result.

EDIT: I would like to understand POST method and the "proper" way to get the data from the json object if getParameter is wrong please~

Answer (score -1):

`getParameter()` returns http request parameters, you should add this params by using :

```
params: JSON.stringify(json)
```

Not with

```
request: JSON.stringify(json)
```

Take a look in [params in get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request) and [params in post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957248/how-to-send-post-in-angularjs-with-multiple-params).

Comment: no...should be `data` for a post...read the docs. And no need to stringify when that is already done internally

Comment: Yes but he wants to access request.getParameter - query params and not the post data.

Comment: How do you know the server code isn't wrong and intent is to do a post as per method used in request..... *"I am trying to use angularjs POST"*. You provided next to no explanation

Comment: He posted the server code trying to access query param without any query params added.

Comment: And you gave no explanation about what method you are fixing

Comment: I gave 2 links about how to add params to get/post, I think that it is what he was looking for.

Comment: The posts explains better then me, with more details. I dont think it should get downvoted.

Comment: what would be the proper approach to getting the data from a POST method instead of the getParameter? please explain?