# Pass more than one parameter(independent parameter) in http request

Tags: angularjs

This is my method I just simply passing 3 parameters in a http request.I know we can pass like single object,like this..

```
$scope.sendReq = function (responseStatus) {
    $scope.leaveStatus = responseStatus;
    $scope.leaveNote = $scope.cancelReason;
    $scope.Leave_type_id = $scope.LeaveTypeId;

    $scope.ajaxObj = { 
        leaveStatus: $scope.leaveStatus, 
        leaveNote: $scope.leaveNote, 
        Leave_type_id: $scope.Leave_type_id 
    };

    console.log($scope.ajaxObj)

    var requestHeaders = {
        "content-type" : 'application/json'
    }

    var httpRequest = {
        method: 'post',
        url: "/admin/cancelLeaveRequest",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        data: $scope.ajaxObj
    }

    $http(httpRequest).then(function(response){
        alert("success")
    })
}
```

Now my doubt is, can we pass multiple parameters in post? Instead of send it as single object can we pass like this?

```
var httpRequest = {
    method: 'post',
    url: "/admin/cancelLeaveRequest",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    data:  $scope.leaveStatus, $scope.leaveNote , $scope.Leave_type_id 
}
```

Comment: may be this answer might help....https://stackoverflow.com/a/30957308/2967711

Comment: yah already saw this

Comment: You can post an array: `data:  [$scope.leaveStatus, $scope.leaveNote , $scope.Leave_type_id]`