# Send data from Asp.net core to Asp.net Mvc with angualrjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two projects `Asp.net Core` and `Asp.net Mvc`.
I wand to send data from the first project(`Asp.net Core`) to the second project(`Asp.net Mvc`) with angualrjs

When i run two projects ,my problem is that when I want to post Model from `Asp.net Core` to `ActionResult` in `Asp.net Mvc` , this `ActionResult` doesn't have value.

Angularjs in first project(`Asp.net Core`):

```
$rootScope.PrintCArd2 = function () {
    $scope.TblFishCar = {};
    $scope.TblFishCar.IdFish = $rootScope.TblFishCarIdFish;


    $http.post("http://localhost:61779/Report/GetFishReport", $scope.TblFishCar).then(function (result) {
        alert("Ok2");
    },
        function (e) {
            alert("warning"+e);
        }); 
};
```

ActionResult in second projcet(`Asp.net Mvc`):

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFishReport([FromBody]TblFishCar model)
    {
        //do something
        return PartialView("_ShowReport");
    }
}
```

angularjs calls public `ActionResult GetFishReport([FromBody]TblFishCar model)` but model doesn't has value.

TblFishCar:

```
 public partial class TblFishCar
{
    public Guid IdFish { get; set; }
    public int ShFish { get; set; }
    public string DateFish { get; set; }
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show your `TblFishCar model` class? Also, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957248/how-to-send-post-in-angularjs-with-multiple-params/30957308#30957308

Comment: yes edited my post

Comment: Change `Guid` to `string` in the model class and remove `[FromBody]` from the method argument. You could cast the string to guid later in method body(if need be!).

Comment: i use this link , but GetFishReport doesn't has value.

Comment: Please update your post as to what change did you make? Also, `console.log($scope.TblFishCar)` to check if `IdFish` property has value before post?

Comment: this $scope.TblFishCar has value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151350/discussion-between-mohammad-daliri-and-sajal).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the developer tools of the browser to see the real errors.
Also you should enable `cross origin requests` in your MVC app:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```