# How to send two Array objects using http in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http

How to receive two parameters as an array in http action(List abc, List) xyz.
after that attempt I use a model class. lik

```
  public class ItemAndChecque
    {
        public List<SaleItem> saleitem { get; set; }
        public List<itemChecqe> itemchecq { get; set; }
    }
public IHttpActionResult TowArrayValue(List<ItemAndChecque> abc)
```

I did many attempt to solve it but not... Some one can send me any Solution.

Comment: check here. I think thats what youre looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957248/how-to-send-post-in-angularjs-with-multiple-params
otherwise please add more detail or example code of your work

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays need to be grouped in one object array:

```
var Indata = {saleitem: $scope.saleitem,itemchecq: $scope.itemchecq}
$http({
  url: "someAPI",
  method: "POST",
  data: Indata
});
```

Add ItemAndChecque as model class to your backend.

Then you can receive it in your API Controller like this:

```
public void Post(ItemAndChecque request)
{
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var newProduct = productRepository.Save(request.product);
}
```

Here `request` contains 2 props with values of saleitem and itemchecq

Edit: based on the comment of @Icycool

Comment: should use `data` instead of `params` in POST