# How to pass two different types parameters in http POST method using angularjs to Web API?

Tags: angularjs, webapi2

First parameter is a complex type object(JSON) and second parameter is a simple type(String).Here I am using Web API 2.

I am putting my code below.

**Web API**

```
 public class UserDetailsModel
 {
    [Key]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string LoginEmail { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DisplayPic { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string AlternateEmail { get; set; }

    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfRegister { get; set; }

    //public string LoginIP { get; set; }
    public int LoginFlag { get; set; }
}

public int RegisterUser(UserDetailsModel userReg, string LoginIP)
 {
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

**angularjs**

```
var UserDetails = {
                'LoginEmail': $scope.LoginEmail,
                'LoginName': $scope.LoginName,
                'Password': $scope.Password,
                'DoB': $scope.DoB,
                'Gender': $scope.Gender,
                'City': $scope.City,
                'State': $scope.State,
                'Country': $scope.Country
};
var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: urlBase + '/UserDetails',
        params: { 'userRegJSON': UserDetails, 'LoginIP': LoginIP }
    });
```

Here in above code, I am getting NULL in UserDetails and 192.152.101.102 in LoginIP in Web API.

```
var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: urlBase + '/UserDetails',
        data: { 'userRegJSON': UserDetails, 'LoginIP': LoginIP }
    });
```

Here in above code, I am getting NULL in both parameter UserDetails and LoginIP in Web API.

Then how to pass two or more different parameter types in http POST method using angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass 2 types in webAPI.Either you pass everything in a single type or you can do the below

```
var request = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: urlBase + '/UserDetails?LoginIp=' + LoginIP,
    data: UserDetails,

});
```

In the API change the signature to

```
public int RegisterUser([FromBody]UserDetailsModel userReg, [FromUri]string LoginIP)
{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: Now it is working. But I have one question. If I remove [FromBody] and [FromUri] from Parameters, It is also working. So what is the best way and Why?

Comment: Yes those are for a cleaner code not mandatory in this situation.Say if you have 2 complex types in that case you need to prefix which type is coming from body and which one will be in query string.

Answer (score 0):

Webapi doesn't work fairly well when you wish to pass 2 parameters in a `POST`
method. ModelBinding in Webapi always works against a single object because it maps a model. 
There a few workarounds that you can use to make this work:

Use both POST *and* QueryString Parameters in Conjunction
If you have both complex and simple parameters, you can pass simple parameters on the query string. Your code should actually work with:
something like this

```
/baseUri/UserDetails?LoginIP=LoginIP
```

but that's not always possible. In this example it might not be a good idea to pass a user token on the query string though.

Refer to @Ravi A's [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39264375/3872578) for making changes in your code.

Comment: Actually we can pass complex type using GET as well. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814160/how-to-pass-complex-object-to-asp-net-webapi-get-from-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: My apologies, Yes I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Go throught this:
Use  simple and complex types in my api method signatures
[POST multiple objects from Angular controller to Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829124/post-multiple-objects-from-angular-controller-to-web-api-2)